# How to get Xamarin form each CollectionView item?

Tags: c#, xamarin

### *I wanna change each ItemsSource,but I don't know how to do it?*

A simple Code blow:

- ```
    async private void SearchBar_SearchButtonPressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ClassA ChangeTextA = new ClassA();
        CollectionView BKcv = new CollectionView();
        BKcv.ItemsSource = await MyDB.search(ChangeTextA.Change(sbar.Text));
        //How to get each item and make some change?
        myCV.ItemsSource = BKcv.ItemsSource;
    }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items = await MyDB.search(ChangeTextA.Change(sbar.Text));

foreach (var x in items)
{
  // change some properties on x
}

BKcv.ItemsSource = items;
```